# Should Voldemort have been the true owner of the elder wand?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Deathly Hallows Harry and Voldemort are fighting in the forest. Voldemort defeats and kills Harry, why didn't Voldemort become the true owner of the Elder Wand and therefore win their final battle?

Comment: Because harry is the true owner of it, can not kill one with his wand.

Comment: If Harry cannot be killed with the wand whilst he is the owner, how did he die and the Horcrux be destroyed? Shouldn't the wand have backfired like it did during their final battle?

Comment: Some says that's harry doesn't die, just the Horcrux destroyed and harry have some kind of near-death experience.

Comment: A Horcrux that has a living container can only be destroyed with their death therefore Harry must have died in order to destroy the Horcrux

Comment: Could someone be described as "defeated" if they never defended themselves?

Comment: @SimonAspinall The answer to why Harry didn't die and is already given here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/177937/91540

Comment: @AdrianWragg Excellent point. That was Dumbledore's original plan anyways. To die as owner of Elder wand undefeated (since his death was planned already with Snape)

Comment: @dobby although that gives some explanation as to why Harry didn't die, it doesn't explain how the horcrux was destroyed. To destroy a horcrux one must damage the object containing the horcrux beyond all physical and magical repair. In the case the horcrux has a living container the only way to destroy the horcrux is to kill them.

Comment: @AdrianWragg I guess they can't. But Dumbledore did not defend himself against Malfoy meaning he was never the owner of the Elder Wand.

Comment: @SimonAspinall The "Container of Horcrux" i.e. Harry did die. It's just that his death was not absolute like a normal death of any person because he had a choice to either go back and fight or go "on" (in which case he would have chosen to remain dead).

Comment: @dobby When Harry was dead, why didn't the wand's allegiance chance to Voldemort?

Comment: @SimonAspinall An interesting point. I haven't got the book to hand to check the exchange, but did he willingly allow himself to be disarmed?

Comment: @AdrianWragg Dumbledore non-verbally froze Harry instead of defending himself and I guess that's what makes the difference. It's not that he did not want to defend himself but that he found it more important to keep Harry from harms way.

Comment: @SimonAspinall It would have IF Harry had decided to remain dead, but Harry chose to come back and hence he was still undefeated. Voldemort's curse failed to permanently kill Harry.

Comment: @dobby regardless of Harry coming back, he was still defeated by Voldemort

Comment: No. Harry wasn't defeated by Voldemort. Read the other comments.